# Angularjs - ng-repeat generating empty elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a array which have improper key order, like

```
1: Array[1]
2: Array[2]
4: Array[3]
7: Array[14]
21: Array[1]
22: Array[1]
23: Array[1]
```

So when I iterate using `ng-repeat`, empty elements and generated for key values which are not there.

So here it will generate elements for keys 1 and 2, and as there is no key 3, it will generate an empty div there.Same happens after 4.three empty elements are generated.How can this be fixed ?

Comment: Please post some code or create JSFiddle.

Comment: do you mean that the "missing" positions are empty?

Comment: Issue is with your array generation (You are creating sparse array possibly setting value with arr[index]= value instead of arr.push), can you show that piece of code. Try to fix at the source rather than working around it.

Comment: WIthout seeing your array is difficult to understand what do you want

Answer (score 0):

You can either fix the array by creating a new array with proper values or you can add a check in the view for not null or undefined.

Fix the array

```
var myArray = [[1], [1,2], null, [1,2,3]];
var newArray = [];
angular.forEach(function (myArray, function (a) {
  if (a & a.length) { 
    newArray.push(a);
  }
})l;
```

Now you can use the new array to render the view

Or fix in the view

```
<div ng-repeat="item in myArray">
   <div ng-if="item !== null && item !== undefined">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use object?

```
"array":[
    {"key":"1", "content":[]}, 
    {"key":"2", "content":[]}, 
    {"key":"5", "content":[]}, 
    {"key":"3", "content":[]}
]
```

Comment: Yes like a dictionary.